# how to get the record id from url to controller extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

https://cs9.salesforce.com/a1mK0000000t4sM

i am trying to get the id from the above url
by
using the below two options

first option:

```
id urlid=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
```

second option:

```
id urlid=system.currentpagereference().getparameters().get('id');
```

here i am not getting that url id 
can any one suggest me ..............

Comment: If that's your URL, you're not even using a Visualforce page. The correct format would be https://c.cs9.visual.force.com/apex/mypage?id=a1mK0000000t4sM (or similar).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have written a extension to Account standard controller, you can get the id as given below.

```
public with sharing class AcctControllerExtn {
    private final Account acct;

    public AcctControllerExtn (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        Id CustNo = acct.Id; 

    }
```